# не работает миграция БД Spring Fly Way

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, flyway

Создал первую версию миграции(sql скрипт). В sql файле просто скрипт создания 3-ех таблиц(users, messages, user_roles)

Проблемы начинаются при добавлении второй версии, вот содержимое:

```
insert into users (id, username, password, email, active)
values (1, 'albuquerque', '123', 'albuquerque.maks@gmail.com', true);

insert into user_roles (user_id, role)
values (1, 'USER'), (1, 'ADMIN');
```

IDE подчеркивает имена таблиц и имена столбцов.(Будто их нет)

Стектрейс ошибки:

```
SQL State  : 42703
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: column "role" of relation "user_roles" does not exist
  Position: 34
Location   : db/migration/V2__Add_admin.sql (/home/albuquerque/Documents/TwitterGit/Messenger-master/first-witter/target/classes/db/migration/V2__Add_admin.sql)
Line       : 4
Statement  : insert into user_roles (user_id, role)
values (1, 'USER'), (1, 'ADMIN')

2019-10-10 17:06:54.118  INFO 15781 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-10-10 17:06:54.137  INFO 15781 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2019-10-10 17:06:54.141  INFO 15781 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-10-10 17:06:54.156  INFO 15781 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-10 17:06:54.165 ERROR 15781 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
Migration V2__Add_admin.sql failed
----------------------------------
SQL State  : 42703
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: column "role" of relation "user_roles" does not exist
  Position: 34
Location   : db/migration/V2__Add_admin.sql (/home/albuquerque/Documents/TwitterGit/Messenger-master/first-witter/target/classes/db/migration/V2__Add_admin.sql)
Line       : 4
Statement  : insert into user_roles (user_id, role)
values (1, 'USER'), (1, 'ADMIN')

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.twitter.firstwitter.FirsTwitterApplication.main(FirsTwitterApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
Migration V2__Add_admin.sql failed
----------------------------------
SQL State  : 42703
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: column "role" of relation "user_roles" does not exist
  Position: 34
Location   : db/migration/V2__Add_admin.sql (/home/albuquerque/Documents/TwitterGit/Messenger-master/first-witter/target/classes/db/migration/V2__Add_admin.sql)
Line       : 4
Statement  : insert into user_roles (user_id, role)
values (1, 'USER'), (1, 'ADMIN')

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.doMigrateGroup(DbMigrate.java:370) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$200(DbMigrate.java:54) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$3.call(DbMigrate.java:284) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:74) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.applyMigrations(DbMigrate.java:281) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrateGroup(DbMigrate.java:246) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$100(DbMigrate.java:54) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.call(DbMigrate.java:164) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.call(DbMigrate.java:161) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.postgresql.PostgreSQLAdvisoryLockTemplate.execute(PostgreSQLAdvisoryLockTemplate.java:71) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.postgresql.PostgreSQLConnection.lock(PostgreSQLConnection.java:104) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory.lock(JdbcTableSchemaHistory.java:155) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrateAll(DbMigrate.java:161) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:139) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1395) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1356) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1711) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1356) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.FlywaySqlScriptException: 
Migration V2__Add_admin.sql failed
----------------------------------
SQL State  : 42703
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: column "role" of relation "user_roles" does not exist
  Position: 34
Location   : db/migration/V2__Add_admin.sql (/home/albuquerque/Documents/TwitterGit/Messenger-master/first-witter/target/classes/db/migration/V2__Add_admin.sql)
Line       : 4
Statement  : insert into user_roles (user_id, role)
values (1, 'USER'), (1, 'ADMIN')

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.handleException(DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.java:253) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.executeStatement(DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.java:202) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.execute(DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.java:125) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationExecutor.execute(SqlMigrationExecutor.java:77) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.doMigrateGroup(DbMigrate.java:367) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "role" of relation "user_roles" does not exist
  Position: 34
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:266) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcTemplate.executeStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:235) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.StandardSqlStatement.execute(StandardSqlStatement.java:42) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.executeStatement(DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.java:189) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

2-ой файл миграции не видит этих созданных таблиц и не может ничего туда вставить. Таблицы точно есть, проверил через терминал.

Приложение на Spring-Boot

Из настроек Fly Way добавил:

```
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
```

И в файл `pom.xml` зависимость и плагин.

Comment: Мало информации, чтобы понять причину. По ошибке можно сказать лишь, что в файле "V2__Add_admin.sql" инсерты, которые фейлятся, потому что схема неправильная. Как вариант,  сделайте mvn flyway:clean и потом mvn flyway:migrate.

Comment: Я сейчас убрал эту настройку - `spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true` и все заработало. Что делает эта настройка и как она создает такую проблему? Не могу найти внятного объяснения.